# bucket sort Implementation without using vector,pointer and counting sort

Tags: c, sorting, bucket-sort

We want to use Bucket sort to sort numbers between 1 to 2001. the count of numbers can be 10E6.

I know the bucket sort algorithm. But the issue is that in this question, **we are not permitted to use variable-length array, vector and pointer**. (The only pointer related thing allowed is "pass by reference" of the array) The only solution I found is using using counting sort for each bucket, like the code below, so the code is more like counting sort than the bucket sort: (C language)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int buckets[201][10]={}; int numbers[1000001]={};

void bucket_sort (int a[],int n) {
    for (int i =0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        int index = a[i]/10, index2 = a[i]%10;
        buckets[index][index2]++;
    }
    int counter =0;
    for (int i =0;i<=200;i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<=9;j++)
        {
            while (buckets[i][j])
            {
                a[counter] = i*10+j; 
                counter++;
                buckets[i][j]--;
            }
        }
    } }

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i =0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&numbers[i]);
        numbers[i]; 
    }
    bucket_sort(numbers,n);
    for (int i =0;i<=n-1 ;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0; }
```

I want to know can bucket sort be implemented without variable-length array, vector and pointer and also without counting sort. Probably using Insertion or Bubble sort. Note that it must be a reasonable bucket-sort algorithm. So defining  very big buckets like `int bucket [201][1000000];` is also an unacceptable approach.

Comment: what about just computing the bucket an element belongs to. If the the bucket is full, either put the smallest element in the previous bucket or the largest in the next bucket, etc. If the elements are roughly uniformly distributed it doesn't seem so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't use variable length arrays or pointers, one of which is required for a bucket sort, your best bet is to go with a counting sort.  You only have 2000 possible values, so create an array of size 2000 and for each value you find increments the corresponding array element.

```
void counting_sort(int a[], int n)
{
    int count[2002] = { 0 };
    int i, j; 

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        count[a[i]]++;
    }

    for (i=0, j=0; i<n; i++) {
        while (!count[j]) {
            j++;
        }
        a[i] = j;
        count[j]--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, my program is also a type of counting sort. I want to know whether any other sorting method exists that can be implemented with these conditions or not.

Comment: Actually, what you have is a form of bucket sort.  The buckets are the first 3 digits of the number in question, then each bucket uses a counting sort on the last digit.  So technically is qualifies.